# Hasmap returns duplicate keys

Tags: java, data-structures, hashmap

I have s scanner that parse file and puts index 1 and 2 into a hashmap.

lets say k1 = 5 and a next k1 = 5

it will print out: 5 and 10
while I want to only ad the values and show only one key. So i want the values to be added and be "10"

```
while (scanner.hasNextLine()) {             
    InputLine = scanner.nextLine();
    String[] arr = InputLine.split("\t");

    if(map.containsKey(arr[1])){
        map.put(arr[1], map.get(arr[1]) + Integer.parseInt(arr[2]));
        }
    else
    {
        map.put(arr[1], Integer.parseInt(arr[2]));
    }               
    System.out.println(map.get(arr[1]));
    }
```

Comment: What's the problem with your code? What's your question?

Comment: yes it does.
Lets say <String, Integer>
it reads in :<ID1, 5> and next iteration it reads in <ID1, 6>

Instead of returning just 11 it returns 5 and then 11 on the next line

Comment: If you iterate 2 lines, why would you expect it to print only once?

Comment: because I want to let the Key be unique in the hashmap and add the value if it find a identical key in the text and only print that unique key and value added.

I have a textfile with identical IDs and different values to them. I want to sum all the values everytime that same ID is read but sum all the values and assign it to that ID.

So I put the splitted text into arr[1] and [arr2] into a hashmap. for each line it reads. If the next arr[1] is identical it should only put it back into the map and add the new value to the old value in the arr[2]

Comment: I haven't asked what you want. I've asked why you think your code would behave that way. You have a `System.out.println` within a loop. It will get executed on each iteration.

Answer (score -1):

That can be only one meaningful answer for this. 
First, no duplicate key can be stored in a "Set". So every single "key" has a unique hashcode. You use "String" as keys. After parsing your line, second  element of your array becomes your key.

You say you have two 5's.

```
XX        5//ends up with no chars
YY        5 //ends up with a white-space
```

For the row XX, your first key is absolutely "5". 
Fot the row YY, your key becomes "5 ".

Two strings have different hashcodes. That's why they can be stored in a key "Set".

Check your file before or after "\t" character. Be sure if there is another character after or before numbers.